Why did Godwin Baxter sew money into her dress?
In Poor Things (2023), Student Maxcandles stops Bella, his future wife, from seeing Duncan, leading her
to chloroform him. Godwin Baxter then arrives, sews money in Bella’s
dress, shares a kiss, and departs:

Why did Godwin Baxter sew money into her dress?

It's for her to use in an emergency. Sewing it into the lining means it is unlikely to be discovered or used by anyone other than Bella, particularly the oily little homunculus she's running off with.
Per the script.

BELLA: Good bye later dove. I will see you after grand adventure.
Baxter comes in clutching a stack of folded notes.
Baxter grabs a dress from her case, rips open the lining, and
swiftly sews the money into the dress with the skill of a
surgeon. She watches him. He stares at her as he does it.
He comes to her, embraces her, then stalks from the room.

Note that what happens to the money is precisely what's intended. Eventually she needs it and goes and gets it.

BELLA: My instinct now tells me you are not that. Our adventure is clearly
over.
She rips open stitching in her dress, pulls God’s bills forth.
BELLA (CONT’D): I shall buy you a passage back to London.
Duncan stares at her.
DUNCAN: You had money?! The whole time!
BELLA: It is God’s money for emergencies.

